# how to do Button submit gets a pop a window with an image directing to other site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, buttonclick

I am trying a submit button to open a pop window with an image, and onclick of that image, a site should open.

Here is my code.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="myImg()" formenctype= "multipart/form-data" style= " width: 8em;  height: 3em; font: bold 14px sans-serif;border-radius:20px;">Send</button>

<SCRIPT>
window.onbeforeunload=confirmExit;
function myImg(){
window.name = "thiswin";
    newwin=open("http://lynx.radiocompetitions.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/lynx-banner.png", "dispwin", 
    "width=250,height=300,scrollbars=no, menubar=no");

       }
</SCRIPT>
```

The problem is, the button is not working.

Comment: its working for me,https://jsfiddle.net/twsq5L43/

Comment: holy cracker..!
then why not me... I am doing this in wordpress. would that make any difference ????

Comment: and also if you can please help me how to use that image to direct the user to another site ..please....

Comment: Sounds like a pop up blocker to me.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload=confirmExit;` Is this `confirmExit` function exists on your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at following fiddle. Hope that will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/twsq5L43/5/

```
function myImg(){
    window.name = "thiswin";
    var imagePath = "http://lynx.radiocompetitions.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/lynx-banner.png";

    newwin=open("", "dispwin", 
    "width=750,height=300,scrollbars=no, menubar=no");

    var otherWebsiteURL = "http://www.google.com";

    newwin.document.write("<div><a href='"+otherWebsiteURL+"'><img src='"+imagePath+"'></a></div>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine.

You did mention in comments that you have put it into wordpress. Make sure it is not conflicting with anything. Have you run a debugger and loaded the page to check ? ( if not use something like firebug plugin for firefox ) run the console and click on the button to see if it returns an error. Wordpress and wordpress plugins can cause allot of headaches.

Check to see where you have placed it, at the very bottom before the closing  or in the header? They can make a difference in placement again depending on plugins you are using and if the developer of those plugins did the right thing when creating them.

Comment: I have placed this code at the very bottom of the form in body.

Comment: what is the website address or can you post the full page code included?